# MongoDB not connecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I currently have a node.js app that uses MongoDB as it's database. When I try to connect it to the database, I keep getting the error:

```
MongoError: not authorized for query on <database_name>.<collection_name>
```

This was working a few months ago, but now it doesn't work. Please tell me what's wrong.

I am using MongoLab.

Comment: If you're using a Sandbox database, they recently underwent maintenance to upgrade to 3.0: http://docs.mongolab.com/20150930-maintenance-event/. It's possible you need to upgrade your driver to one that is compatible with the new auth mechanism in 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking to see if MongoLab is still hosting your stuff.  If you haven't used it in a while, they may have terminated your service.  Log in and give it a quick check before you go any further.

What's your connection string look like?  Can you verify that your username, password, and mongo lab url are all correct (they're pretty long!).